# How to change the order of the items on the blog-layout page for "page-header"?

Tags: joomla-3.x, category

I 'm trying to change the order of the items showing in the `<div class="page-header">`, where the Title comes before the category name, but I want the category name to show before the title of the article.

[image]

I tried using CSS and jQuery to reorder without success, so I guess I need to change the PHP code, but I 'm not sure where or how?

Comment: i should maybe add im working on the blog-layout where i should x categories in a link in the menu. and i have joomla 3.x installed

Answer (score 2):

You need an [**override**](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides) for the layout. Follow the step by step here:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager

Now you need create the override in the column:
**Components** > **com_content** > **category**

[image]

You can find the files in:

`yoursite/templates/yourtemplate/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php`

From here you can change the order for the block that contains *'**show_category**'*.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

It is generaly done by using template override technique. Try searching JSX for "template override" or so. Good staring point might be a question "[Joomla 3 category blog article override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667039/joomla-3-category-blog-article-override?rq=1)"

Comment: thanks for reply. i already know that, but my problem is i can't find the file to edit.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure either. Joomla 3 introduced new layout overrides, atop of old extension view overrides... I never used new ones yet. Search on Google for "joomla 3 blog view override" gives an interesting link Layout Overrides in Joomla https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla in JDOCS. You might check on that...

Comment: its not the override i have problem with its finding the PHP FILE/CODE. i can't seem to find it anywhere in my blog.layout file.

Comment: The easiest way to find the correct file is to turn off SEF urls and visit the page.  The URL roughly shows you how to find the file.